# How can I customize exceptions thrown when @Produces and @Consumes is violated

Tags: java, rest, ejb

- I'm working on i18n(Internationalization and localization) task of my
  REST services. Now I want to pass the error message according to the
  Accept-Language of the header to the Exceptions thrown when Accept or
  Content-Type of the header's not matched with @Produces and
  @Consumes.
- I found a solution in ContainerRequestFilter, but if I
  check the Accept and Content-Type of the header in that
  ContainerRequestFilter and throw Exception when it's not matched the
  MediaType I want, there will be no need to use @Produces and
  @Consumes again in the Resource.
- So my question is, is there a way to
  customize the exceptions thrown when @Produces and @Consumes is
  violated (I mean NotAcceptableException and NotSupportedException)?
  Because I want to pass the error message in multiple languages to the
  message in these Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ExceptionMapper` which will catch exceptions thrown in your service and return formatted response. It may be customized to handle specific exceptions.

```
@Provider
@Singleton
public class ExceptionMapperProvider implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final Exception exception){
        return Response.status(HttpStatusCodes.STATUS_CODE_SERVER_ERROR).entity(new BasicResponse(InternalStatus.UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION, exception.getMessage())).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know ExceptionMapper, but then I must to declare @Context HttpHeaders to get Accept-Language and then once again declare ResourceBundle to select Language Bundle in the ExceptionMapper. Then If I have another more ExceptionMapper, I must to do it all over again.